# Variation of a Function

Tags: integration

Let $g$ be a function of finite $q$ Variation and $f$ be a function of finite $p$ Variation, and $\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{p}>1$.
What can be said about the variation of $H$ with $$H(t):=\int_{a}^{t}g(s)df(s)\text{ ? }$$

The $p$ variation $Var_{p}(f;[a,b])$ of a Function $f$ over $[a,b]$ is defined as:
$$Var_{p}(f;[a,b])=\sup \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|f(t_{i})-f(t_{i-1})\right|^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

where the supremum runs over all partitions of $[a,b]$

If $f$ would be monotone on $[a.b]$ then I could use a mean value theorem for RS Integrals. 
Is there a similar mean Value theorem for a function $f$ which is not monotone?
I think, that then I could conclude: 
$H$ has finite $p$ variation.

I have alread asked this on mathstackexchange

Comment: Since $g$ is bounded, if you view it as a limit of step functions you should get a bound for the $q$-variation of $H$, regardless of $p$, as long as $q\geq 1$. Is this the sort of thing you want?

Comment: Can you give a more detailed explanation? I have got the following aim: I want to integrate with respect to $H$. So I want to consider functions $\Psi(t):=\int_{t}^{a}\alpha(s)dH(s)$. So I need to know the smallest number $r$ such that $Var_{r}(H,[a,b])$ is finite.After that I could answer the question for which $\alpha$ the function $\Psi$ is well defined. This would follow from the condition $\frac{1}{w}+\frac{1}{r}>1$